# Positionning correctly text over specific image on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have this dice image [image]

I would like to write text on the grey part, but only on this part. I don't want text overstep black line. How I can do ? Moreover text will be added dynamically.

Comment: I am not quite sure about Android but does it not have something like z-index or position:absolute?

Comment: The real problem is to position text correctly and not writing text.

Comment: I would draw the whole thing + draw the rotated text on it (so to be sure it's scaled properly). It wouldn't be so difficult to paint some lines, some fills and 4 ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution :

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKlmw.png" alt="image" />
    <span>Text over image here!</span>
</div>

 .image {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 175px;
}

.image img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.image span {
    width: 75px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 45px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
    writing-mode: lr-tb;

}
```

Link to jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uvky91gd/

Comment: My bad, I precised I want it for android only with keywords